# How to prove that a non-positive series converges?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

**Given a(n) a series that is monotonic and converges to *zero* which means: a(n)---->0.**

How to prove that the following summation converges for any K (a normal number):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{[n/k]}a(n)$$

Note: `[]` symbol rounds the value down.

---

**What did I do?**

First, I have two options:

**1)** a(n) is a monotonically increasing function. Thus a(n)>=0

**2)** a(n) is a monotonically decreasing function. Thus a(n)<=0

But from here I couldn't continue since all the laws of convergence which I know, only work for positive summation or by proving that the summation in `||` converges which proves that the original converges but that doesn't seem to be the case here *-i.e take 1/n as an example of a(n)-*

Comment: I gave an example in my post that what is given doesn't converge in ||

Comment: If $k=1$ then this is an alternating series and converges by the alternating series test.  Perhaps the ideas in the proof of the alternating series test are of use here.

Comment: it can be 1, 2, ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 etc

Comment: "$a(n)$ is monotonic and converges to $0$", $a(n) \to 0$, no?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Ok, so for example if $k=3$, then $[n/k] = 0$ for $n=1,2$, $1$ for $n=3,4,5$ etc.
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{[n/k]}a(n) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m b(m)$$
where $b(0) = a(1) +a(2)$, $b(1) = a(3)+a(4)+a(5)$.  Since $a(n)$ is moonotonic, to zero, so is $b(m)$ so the series converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: Look at Dirichlet's convergence test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)

Comment: @Malcolm I just finished proving it by going to the basics of how we proved the alternating series test :-( your solution seems much much more simpler and easier. Hope my work worth it.

Comment: kindly publish it a a solution and could you prove formally that bn----->0? using epsilon?